# How to get the center coordinate of an image on Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates, overlay

I have an image as an overlay on Google map, and as I only have upper left coordinate so I have placed the image top left corner on this coordinate and now I want to make it's focus centerilized in app so I have to put the center coordinate in CameraUpdetFactory.newLatLngZoom(centerilizedLatLng , zoomLevel)
This method, So how can I calculate the center coordinate of this image??

Answer (score 1):

To fetch **LatLng** for the center of the Google map just use :

```
mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.getCenter();
```

This returns the center of the LatLngBounds for the visible region on the device. The center is simply the average of the coordinates here.
Please refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html#public-latlng-getcenter-) for detailed explanation.

Happy Coding :)